# Front facing camera recorded not work in android 4.1.2

Tags: java, android

I am using the code for front camera recorder. Its working well in android 4.0.4. but not working in android 4.1.2. Error occurred when start the media recorder. how to fix.

My class:

```
public class RecoredVideo extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnInfoListener {

private Camera myCamera;
private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
File file;
FrameLayout myCameraPreview;
String Webpath;
String localSdpath;
Button recordstart, close,cameraChange;
boolean recording;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String VideoPath;
CountDownTimer mCountDown;
 int myProgress = 0;
 Camera camera = null;
 int currentCameraId;
 int Rotate=270;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
    RecorderPrepare();
    recordstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videostart);
    recordstart.setOnClickListener(this);
    recording = false;

    close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CloseBtn);
    close.setOnClickListener(this);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.recordbar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    cameraChange=(Button) findViewById(R.id.CamerachangeBtn);
    cameraChange.setOnClickListener(this);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
    }

    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
         int index = getFrontCameraId();
         if(index == -1){
             currentCameraId=Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
         }else{
             currentCameraId=Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
         }

        camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        // camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        param.set("cam_mode", 1);

        // startCamera(Camera.Parameters.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

        // param.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
        param.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);

        camera.setParameters(param);// attempt to get a Camera instance
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return camera; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void cameraChange() {

    camera.stopPreview();

    camera.release();


    if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
        currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        Rotate=270;
    }
    else {
        currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        Rotate=90;
    }

    camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, camera);
    myCameraSurfaceView.requestFocus();
    myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.firstrecordview);
    int count=myCameraPreview.getChildCount();
    if(count!=0){
        myCameraPreview.removeAllViews();
    }

    if (myCameraPreview != null && myCameraSurfaceView != null) {
        myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
    }


}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {

    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    // myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();

    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

     VideoPath=initFile().getAbsolutePath();
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(VideoPath);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5242880 * 4);// Set max file size 5M

    //if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
       //mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    //}
    //else {
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(Rotate);
    //}

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder()
            .getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
    Log.i("onInfo:", what + ":::"
            + MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED );
    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED ) {
        Log.i("VIDEOCAPTURE", "Maximum Duration Reached");

        Stop();

    }
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder() {

    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        // mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = null;
        myCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if (myCamera != null) {
        myCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
        myCamera = null;
    }
}

private File initFile() {
    File dir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES),
            this.getClass().getPackage().getName());
    if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {

        this.file = null;
    } else {
        this.file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), new SimpleDateFormat(
                "'MOV_'yyyyMMddHHmmss'.mp4'").format(new Date()));
        System.out.println(this.file + "::::::this.file");
    }
    return this.file;
}

private void RecorderPrepare() {
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if (myCamera == null) {

    }
    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);

    myCameraSurfaceView.requestFocus();

    myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.firstrecordview);

    if (myCameraSurfaceView != null) {

    }
    if (myCameraPreview != null && myCameraSurfaceView != null) {

        myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

    }

}



private void RecordStart() {

    if (recording) {
        recordstart
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_button_inactive_2);
        // stop recording and release camera
        Stop();

    } else {

        // Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
        releaseCamera();

        if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {

            finish();

        }


        recordstart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.record_button_active_2);
        mediaRecorder.start();
        recording = true;

    }

}

private void Stop() {

    if (mediaRecorder != null)
        mediaRecorder.stop();

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mCountDown != null) {
        mCountDown.cancel();
    }
    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
    releaseCamera();
    Intent Intent_imageview = new Intent(RecoredVideo.this,
            ViewAndSend.class);
    Intent_imageview.putExtra("path", VideoPath);
    startActivity(Intent_imageview);
    finish();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("onPause::::00" + ":::::");
    if (mCountDown != null) {
        mCountDown.cancel();
    }
    try {

        releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release
        releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("onPause", e + "");

    }
    finish();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("onPause::::00" + ":::::");
    if (mCountDown != null) {
        mCountDown.cancel();
    }
    try {

        releaseMediaRecorder(); // if you are using MediaRecorder, release
                                // it
        releaseCamera(); // release the camera immediately on pause event
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("onPause", e + "");

    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.videostart) {
        cameraChange.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        RecordStart();
        startTimer1();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.CloseBtn) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (mediaRecorder != null)
            mediaRecorder.stop();
        if (mCountDown != null) {
            mCountDown.cancel();
        }

        releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
        releaseCamera();
        finish();
    }else if(v.getId() == R.id.CamerachangeBtn){
        cameraChange();
    }

}
private void startTimer1() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myProgress=0;
    progressBar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
    progressBar.setMax(60);
    // Log.i("bulb", "msg");
    if (mCountDown != null) {
        mCountDown.cancel();
    }

    mCountDown = new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myProgress++;
            progressBar.setProgress(myProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Log.i("bulb", "msg");
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }.start();

}

}
```

Error :

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
at com.gigglemail.giggle.RecoredVideo.RecordStart(RecoredVideo.java:272)
at com.gigglemail.giggle.RecoredVideo.onClick(RecoredVideo.java:340)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
```

All permission added in manifast xml

Comment: Post your logcat and code

Comment: Post your code please. I had this issue but I need to see your code to confirm my fix.

Comment: add hardware accelerated true in manifest ...

Comment: Thank you for replay ,Updated my code.please check and how to fix problem.